# IronOCR Error while reading Image in Docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, ocr, .net-7.0

I using IronOCR and with asp.net webapi with .net 7. In windows it works fine, when I deploy it to docker and try to use the OCR on a JPG image byte array I get this error(It works fine with PDF)

```
IronTesseract ocr = new IronTesseract();
using (OcrInput input = new OcrInput(data.ToArray())) //error
{
      input.Deskew();
      input.DeNoise();
      input.Invert();
                   
      OcrResult result = ocr.Read(input);
      return Task.FromResult(result.Text);
}
```

Error Call Stack

```
Error in pixReadMemJpeg: function not present
Error in pixReadMem: jpeg: no pix returned
Failed to load image from memory.
      System.Exception: Failed to load image from memory.
       ---> System.Exception: Failed to load image from memory.
       ---> System.IO.IOException: Failed to load image from memory.
         at .(Byte[] )
         at IronOcr.OcrInput.Add(Byte[] imageAsByteArray, CropRectangle ContentArea)
         at IronOcr.OcrInput..ctor(Byte[] Bytes)
```

I added these in my docker after extencive search on the web

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils libgdiplus libc6-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev libpng-dev wget pkg-config gcc g++ make

RUN wget http://www.leptonica.org/source/leptonica-1.80.0.tar.gz && \
    tar -xvf leptonica-1.80.0.tar.gz && \
    cd leptonica-1.80.0 && \
    ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking && \
    make && \
    make install
```

nothing seems to work

Update

According to IronOCR they are suggesting

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-focal AS base

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0-focal AS base
WORKDIR /app
# install necessary packages

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils libgdiplus 
libc6-dev
```

but I am using

> FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base

Answer (score 0):

just load it in anybitmap and make sure its for images and not pdf

```
var bitmap = AnyBitmap.FromBytes(data);
IronTesseract ocr = new IronTesseract();
using (OcrInput input = new OcrInput(bitmap))
{
      input.Deskew();
      input.DeNoise();
      input.Invert();
                   
      OcrResult result = ocr.Read(input);
      return Task.FromResult(result.Text);
}
```